# How do you transform cbinded dataframes into rbinded dataframes?

Tags: r

I can't quite get this to work. What I have is a whole bunch of the similar dataframes (same columns) that have been `cbind`ed together and I want to now get a dataframe that would be the equivalent of having `rbind`ed them.
e.g.

```
# with this
set.seed(117)
df1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,rep(mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), 5),],3)))
            mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
[1,] 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
[2,] 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
[3,] 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
[4,] 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
[5,] 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2

# transform it into this something that looks like this
set.seed(117)
do.call(rbind,lapply(1:3, function(x) mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), 5),]))
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Datsun 7101         22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Dodge Challenger1   15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
```

Bonus points if you can add an indicator column specifying which data block it came from (i.e. in our example, each group of 5 observations would be marked 1, 2, or 3 by a column "set").

Thank you for your help. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `split` the sequence of columns in 'df1' by the column names of 'df1', `subset`, concatenate (`c`) the columns, and then convert to 'data.frame'

```
data.frame(lapply(split(1:ncol(df1), colnames(df1)), function(i) c(df1[,i])))
```

NOTE: `data.frame` cannot have duplicated row names.

A slightly more compact option  would be to `split` the dataset after replicating the column names, wrap it with `data.frame` to convert the `list` to `data.frame`.

```
data.frame(split(df1, colnames(df1)[col(df1)]))
```

---

EDIT: Both the above methods were based on the assumption that the OP's dataset is `matrix` (before the edit in OP's post).  If the initial dataset is `data.frame`, we change `c` in the first method to `unlist`

```
df2 <- data.frame(lapply(split(1:ncol(df1), colnames(df1)), 
            function(i) unlist(df1[,i], use.names=FALSE)) )
```

If we need to create an indicator column specifying the data block, we can use `ave` to create the sequence based on the column names

```
df2$ind <- ave(seq_along(df1), colnames(df1), FUN=seq_along)
```

Comment: This works as long as df1 is a matrix. Is there a method for data frames? The multiple columns with the same names are coming back as sameName.1, sameName.2, sameName.3, etc.

Comment: @jks612 I thought your input dataset is `matrix`.

Comment: That did it. THANK YOU!